# Cannot read property 'episodes' of undefined in a array [vuejs]

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

**Problem**

Hi devs,

I am building an app of movies and series with an api that I developed. I have the problem that when I want to access a video section it does not let me in since the value of season_list [season_selected - 1] .episodes is undefined.

I have three options available in the section:

- 1 Option: Select season
- 2 Option: Select chapter
- 3 Option: Select videos

I can enter the section if I change `javascripts season_list [season_selected - 1].episodes` by `javascripts season_list[season_selected - 1]`.

Here is the example of json, particularly in the part of season_list
https://cinemanight.chrismichael.now.sh/api/v1/search/elite

You will notice that the season_list has two values, season and episodes. This is why I need to use episodes like season_list [season_selected - 1] .episodes

**Error**

```sh
"vue.runtime.esm.js? 2b0e: 1888 TypeError: Cannot read property 'episodes' of undefined"
```

The error is referring to the following line

```
season_list[season_selected - 1].episodes
```

**Template Section**

```
<select class="container" v-model="season_selected">
   <option disabled value="">Temporadas</option>
   <option  v-for="(season , index) in Array.from({length: total_seasons}, (v , k) => k + 1)" :value="season" :key="index">
       {{ season }}
    </option>
 </select>

<select class="container" v-model="episode_selected">
    <option disabled value="">Episodios</option>
    <option v-for="(epis , index) in season_list[season_selected - 1].episodes" :value="epis" :key="index">
       {{ epis }}
    </option>
 </select>
<select class="container" v-model="option">
  <option disabled value="">Videos</option>
  <option v-for="(video , index) in serie_video.map(xs => xs.iframe)" :value="video" :key="index">
    {{ video }}
  </option>
</select>
```

**Script Section**

```
<script>
  import {value , watch} from 'vue-function-api';
  import {useState , useStore , useRouter} from '@u3u/vue-hooks';

  export default{
    name: 'SerieVideo',
    setup(){
      const store = useStore();
      const {route} = useRouter();

      const state = {
        ...useState(['serie_video' , 'isLoading'])
      };

      const params = {
        id: value(route.value.params.id),
        title: value(route.value.params.title),
        sinopsis: value(route.value.params.sinopsis),
        extra: value(route.value.params.extra)
      };

      const values = {
        title: params.title.value,
        sinopsis: params.sinopsis.value,
        channel: params.extra.value[0].channel,
        first_air_date: params.extra.value[0].first_air_date.replace('First air date' , ''),
        last_air_date: params.extra.value[0].last_air_date.replace('Última transmisión' , ''),
        creator_member: params.extra.value[0].cast_members,
        members_list: params.extra.value[0].cast_members,
        season_list: params.extra.value[0].season_list
      };

      const total_seasons = value(values.season_list);
      const season_list = value(values.season_list);
      const season_selected = value(null);
      const episode_selected = value(null);
      const id = value(null)
      const option = value("");


      watch(() =>
        episode_selected.value , (value) =>{
          episode_selected.value = value;
          const eps = episode_selected.value;
          const id = `${params.id.value.replace('ver-' , '')}-${eps}`
          store.value.dispatch("GET_VIDEO_SERIES" , id)
        }
      );


      return{
        ...state,
        ...values,

        option,
        season_selected: season_selected.value,
        episode_selected: episode_selected.value,
        season_list: season_list.value,
        total_seasons: total_seasons.value.length
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**I have a solution but it has a bug**
And is that in episodeList every time I select a season it makes me push and if I choose the same season again it makes me push. And I can see this quickly when I have a select for episodes, it shows me a list of the seasons I have selected and not just one.

I want to find a way not to push using episodesList

**Template seccion**

```
<select class = "container" v-model = "episode_selected">
  <option disabled value = ""> Episodes </option>
  <option v-for = "(epis, index) in episodesList [season_selected - 1]": value = "epis": key = "index">
   {{epis}}
   </option>
</select>
```

**Sscript Seccion**

```
const episodesList = value ([])

watch (() =>
  season_selected.value, (value) => {
  season_selected.value = value
  const selected = season_selected.value; // season selected
  episodesList.value.push (season_list [selected - 1] .episodes); // list of episodes
 }
);
```

**FINAL SOLUTION**
Problem corrected by adding the value 1 to the variable `const season_selected = value(1);`. Then a watch will be used to be aware that its value is updated.

Setting the value 1 will let me start the video section and having season 1 selected. But then the user can make the change in the select.

Comment: When that happens, what is the value of `season_selected`?

Comment: @Pointy Hello

The value of season_selected is a list of all seasons from 1 to N,
but I have to use [season_selected - 1] for how season_list is a list because the indexes start from zero, for example if in season_selected I select 1 it would be zero and I would return the array

{
               "season": 1,
               "episodes": [
                 "1x1",
                 "1x2",
                 "1x3",
                 "1x4",
                 "1x5",
                 "1x6",
                 "1x7",
                 "1x8"
               ]
             },

Comment: @Pointy I added a solution but it has a bug, check above, I did an update

Comment: @Pointy I found a solution.... :)